# Pentaho Report Designer 5: strange behaviour in Excel multiple sheets

Tags: excel, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I'm making a report with PRD 5.1.0 Community Edition, and I'm trying to create an Excel output with multiple sheets.

All the data are already grouped by a column (the customer id in this case) so I've set the "pagebreak-after" value to "True" in the Group Footer.

**In the Excel output it indeed prints the document with a single sheet per customer, problem is the related data from the second sheet onward starts from the last row of the previous sheet, leaving a lot of blank rows at the top.**

*For instance, if the data table in the first sheet ends in row 41, the table in the second sheet will start from row 42, leaving the previous 41 rows blank.*

The problem appears only with Excel output: trying to print the report as a PDF output works fine.

[DETAIL] Sadly, I cannot use a different version of PRD nor upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

[I'm not voting this, keeping the question open if someone knows a cleaner way to achieve this.Still I'm posting what I've found if someone is having the same trouble].

So I tried one of the working examples to see what mine was missing. It turns out page break won't work in Excel except when you have a subreport in you group header or group footer (even an empty one).

I don't know if it is a bug solved in more recent versions (we sadly have to stick with this version) or if there is a reason behind this behaviour.

In the meantime I found this workaround and now everything works fine :D